# How to DM user using discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a bot on Discord.js. The bot will give a role to every user. The problem is I want the bot DM the role to each user. The code was just not working for me.

What I've tried:

`client.users.get('id').send('Blabla')`, but it didn't work.

`message.author.send("Blabla.")` would only send the message to the author.

`message.channel.send("Blabla")` would only send the message to a channel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`client.users.get('id').send('Blabla')` did not work because in discord.js v12 you have to use the new cache system, in your case it's [`UserManager#cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=cache).

So your solution is: `client.users.cache.get('id').send('Blabla')`